# Trigger mysql para inserir o id desejado

Tags: mysql

Tenho dois banco de dados mysql e sqlserver, compartilho os mesmos dados entre si, porem para não ter conflito de id numerei cada banco mysql = 2, sqlserver = 1,  gostaria que o id da tabela seja inserido pelo mysql, número do banco + id do pedido. Por exemplo:

```
banco mysql -> 2
id cidade auto_incremente ->38
salvo na tabela cidade primary key id = 238
```

Então fiz esse código

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Cidade_Insert AFTER INSERT
ON cidade
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

declare @idString varchar(10);
declare @idInt int;
declare @idLast int;
declare @nomeCidade varchar(50);
declare @totalCaracteres int;

set @idInt = NEW.idCidade
set @idInt = @idInt - 1
set @idString = CONVERT(@idInt, char)
set @totalCaracteres =  LENGTH(@idString)
set @idString = SUBSTRING(@idString, 2, @totalCaracteres - 1)
set @idInt = CONVERT(@idString, int)
set @idInt = @idInt + 1
set @idString = '1'
set @idString = @idString + CONVERT(@idInt, varchar(10))
set @idInt = CONVERT(@idString, int)

set @idLast = NEW.idCidade
set @nomeCidade = NEW.nomeCidade

insert cidade(id_cidade, nome_cidade) values(@idInt, @nomeCidade)
delete from cidade where id_cidade = @idLast

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

Então estou tentando criar uma trigger, já criei no sql server agora falta o Mysql, está dando seguinte erro:

```
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '@idString varchar(10);
declare @idInt int;
declare @idLast int;
declare @nome' na linha 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema usando:
auto_increment_increment e auto_increment_offset.
dessa forma:

```
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

Assim o id vai ser preenchido dessa forma:

```
id
2
12
22
32
...
```